# Combining Data from two JavaScript Objects in a new one

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have an object in JavaScript with the following format:

```
{
'date' : {"12.12.2014","12.12.2014","12.12.2014","13.12.2014","13.12.2014","14.12.2014"}
'product' :  {"apple","banana","apple","strawberry","apple","banana"}
}
```

This object has to be splitted and calculated in the this format:

```
var apple = {
'date': {"12.12.2014","13.12.2014","14.12.2014"}
'product': {2,1,0}
}

var banana = {
'date': {"12.12.2014","13.12.2014","14.12.2014"}
'product': {1,0,1}
}

var strawberry = {
'date' : {"12.12.2014","13.12.2014","14.12.2014"}
'product': {0,1,0}
}
```

Maybe you can provide a solution.

Comment: i don't get the logic of those `product : {1,0,1}` - how are the numbers generated?

Comment: It's the count of the product per date. On the first date one, on the second none, and on the third one.

Comment: this notation `{apple,banana,apple,strawberry,apple,banana}` is invalid. Show the actual object structure

Comment: I updated the Object.

Comment: Please use proper square brackets for arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a proper data structure and some helper `date` and `dateObj`, you get first all dates, second an object as hash table for the dates and third the grouped result.

```js
var object = { 'date': ["12.12.2014", "12.12.2014", "12.12.2014", "13.12.2014", "13.12.2014", "14.12.2014"], 'product': ["apple", "banana", "apple", "strawberry", "apple", "banana"] },
    date = object.date.filter(function (d) {
        if (!this[d]) {
            this[d] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }, Object.create(null)),
    dateObj = {},
    grouped = {};

date.forEach(function (d, i) {
    dateObj[d] = i;
});

object.product.forEach(function (p, i) {
    grouped[p] = grouped[p] || {
        date: date,
        product: date.map(function (d) { return 0; })
    };
    grouped[p].product[dateObj[object.date[i]]]++;
});

console.log(grouped);
```